# How to make the Device Partitioning Numbers in Order (example: "/dev/sda1 to sda5"}

Tags: partitioning

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 OS alone with GPT Partitioning Style.

I have several times installed dual OS, removed one OS etc.
I never let my data to erase.
In regards to this I am only deleting the partitions like `EFI`, `MSReserved`, `OEM`, `/`, `/home`, `swap` etc.

I want to know why `/dev/sda` shows irregular numbers like below and how can I make them in order.. I want to see the below table in this order.. `sda1` `sda2` `sda3` `sda4` and `sda5`

```
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors  
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes  
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes  
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes  
Disklabel type: gpt  
Disk identifier: 918BD4B2-E90D-4F50-8E3E-4EFE6B86495D


Device          Start        End   Sectors   Size Type  
/dev/sda1        2048     194559    192512    94M EFI System  
/dev/sda2      194560   65298431  65103872    31G Linux filesystem  
/dev/sda3    65298432  488957951 423659520   202G Linux filesystem  
/dev/sda6   488957952 1221242879 732284928 349.2G Microsoft basic data  
/dev/sda7  1221242880 1953523711 732280832 349.2G Microsoft basic data
```

[image]

**Update: Issue solved with @crass answer.**
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `sgdisk` from the `gdisk` package to sort the entries.  This can be done by issuing the below command.

```
sgdisk -s /dev/sda
```

> ```
>    -s, --sort
> ```

```
          Sort partition entries. GPT partition numbers need not match the
          order of partitions on the disk. If you want them to match,  you
          can use this option.  Note that some partitioning utilities sort
          partitions whenever they make  changes.  Such  changes  will  be
          reflected  in  your  device  filenames,  so you may need to edit
          /etc/fstab if you use this option.
```

Comment: Nice feature of `gdisk`.  I would have said just use `parted` to delete the partitions and recreate them with exactly the same start and size.

Comment: @PRATAP, if you follow psusi's method correctly (recreating the partitinos at exact same sector values), you won't lose any data... but it can be a scarier thing to do